# Multiple buttons using switch statements and javascript

Tags: javascript, html, button

This is my script.. the var button gets the value of a button.. actually I have multiple buttons with had different values.. But when I click the button, nothing will display.. like its not functioning at all.. Im totally confused >_<

```
function button(form)
        {
            var button = form.buttons.value;
            var display;

            switch (button)
            {
                case 'next':
                    {
                        display = "Next!";
                        break;
                    }
                case 'prev':
                    {
                        display = "Previous!";
                        break;
                    }
                case 'home':
                    {
                        display = "Home!";
                        break;
                    }
                case 'back':
                    {
                        display = "Back!";
                        break;
                    }
            }
        }
            document.getElementById("display").innerHTML = display;
```

This is my sample button.. which is inside the form tag and had an id which is form

```
            <button value="next" name="buttons" onclick="button(this.form)"> Next</button>
```

Comment: where is the element with id "display"? And hit F12 to see 'console' and watch for any js errors or similar. Im also not really liking the "form.buttons.value;", use `console.log('debug',[form,form.buttons,form.buttons.value])` to see if that matches what you expect.

Answer (score 0):

Change this line  var button = form.buttons.value; like this

```
function button(form)
            {
                var button = form.value;
                var display;

                switch (button)
                {
                    case 'next':
                        {
                            display = "Next!";
                            break;
                        }
                    case 'prev':
                        {
                            display = "Previous!";
                            break;
                        }
                    case 'home':
                        {
                            display = "Home!";
                            break;
                        }
                    case 'back':
                        {
                            display = "Back!";
                            break;
                        }
                }
            }
                document.getElementById("display").innerHTML = display;
```

and on your buttons just send  "this"

```
 <button value="next" name="buttons" onclick="button(this)"> Next</button>
```